# Javascript stack traces come up empty

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

The stack traces shown in the Firefox Console are always empty. Am I missing something or might this be a Firefox bug?

Example JS:

```
function foo() {
    bar()
}
function bar() {
    console.trace()
}
foo()
```

Resulting output:
[image]

(Using FF 59 for Ubuntu)

Comment: Looks like you executed the code within [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad) and looking at the results within the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console). You should note that in your question, because code executed within a website does show the stack trace within the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but only the demo code was written in Scratchpad. It doesn't work in other settings either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Firefox 59.0.2, which is already fixed in Firefox Nightly 61.0a1 (2018-04-23).

[image: Stack trace in Browser Console]

Having said that, you just need to make sure where you execute your code. When you execute your code within Scratchpad and check the results within the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), it might not work as expected. Though when you check the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), the stack trace is shown correctly.

Alternatively, there is also the possibility to [run your code within the browser context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad#Running_Scratchpad_in_the_browser_context) to get the expected results.

[image: Stack trace of executing code in browser context shown in Browser Console]

Comment: Thanks. Using the Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K) does in fact give working tracebacks while the Browser Console (Ctrl+Shift+J) doesn't (not only in Scratchpad).
Is it only because it's working on your box or how do you know this was fixed in FF61.0a1?

Comment: I did a quick search on Bugzilla (Mozilla's bug tracker), but couldn't find the exact bug report for that, though it probably has to do with [bug 1439616](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439616), which enabled the new UI within the Browser Console.